# Intellij Plugin set text of current Document

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is there a way to change the whole code in a file from a string?
I mean there is a way to read everything in the Document but can I also replace the whole text?

The way with which you can read the Code in the Document:

`SourceCodeString = e.getData(LangDataKeys.EDITOR).getDocument().getText();`

So I'm basically trying to do the opposite of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the related documentation [Safely Replacing Selected Text in the Document](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics/working_with_text.html#safely-replacing-selected-text-in-the-document):

```
// Replace the selection with a fixed string.
// Must do this document change in a write action context.
WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project, () ->
    document.replaceString(start, end, "editor_basics")
);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to specify the start and end or can you also just replace the whole content?